# $http.post data from modal form (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I'm trying to post the data that is in a modal form on the user hitting send through a HTTP.POST method but I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually access the data object in the post function i have made or if Im even sending it correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated

http.post in index.html:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, data) { 
    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.ok = function() {
        $http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post")
        .then(function (response) {$scope.data = response.data;});
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
```

process post function in app.js:

```
app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format
   //response = req;
   //console.log(req.body.data);
   //res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
})
```

Comment: Is that nodeJS?

Comment: I don't see any data in post function.

Comment: yeah it is node

Comment: i should note i currently dont do anything in the app.post as im not really sure how i access the data i pass right now

Comment: your post function syntax is wrong. you missed data for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out the second param in the $http.Post. Your data object is supposed to be passed into the http.Post function as the second param. It can be as such

```
$http.Post('http://127.0.0.1:8081/process_post', { data: $scope.data })
```

If that is nodeJS + expressJS, you can access the data with req.body.data. It should show the data. If nothing shows with console.log(req.body.data), try removing the middleware urlencodedParser.

**Final Update:**

Add these two lines to get data from nodeJS + expressJS.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: ah awesome yeah just stumbled across the same in the angular documentation for http

Comment: You may want to put your uibModalInstance.close() inside the 'then' function so that it doesn't close the modal if there was an error. Additionally, add a catch block to catch any errors. Typically, I would add a $scope.success = true inside the 'then' function, and a $scope.sucess = false inside the 'catch' function. That will allow me to display a success/error message accordingly.

Comment: hmmm its leaving me with undefined when i print req.body.data when i remove the urlencodedparser it throws an error saying it cant access .body of undefined

Comment: Keep the urlencodedparser then. Test your { data: $scope.data} by doing something like { data : 'testString' }. And retrieve it from node by console.log(req.body.data)

Comment: still undefined as 'testString'

Comment: Are you using the body-parser npm module? If you are, add this to your nodeJS file - app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142322/discussion-between-david-parsonson-and-codemax).

Comment: issue resolved with this answer in conjuction with adding these lines to app.js app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));